# Custom kernel, psci returns "Cannot open /proc/bus/pci"

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, pci

```
sh-4.3# lspci
pcilib: Cannot open /proc/bus/pci
lspci: Cannot find any working access method.
sh-4.3#
```

I am trying to enable PCI support on my IMX6 board, but lspci isn't returning anything.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/pauldotknopf/5434d84a9b51faa7beffba01fd9aeda0) is my `.config`.

What option am I missing in the kernel to enable PCI support?

Comment: 1. Strange that your lspci is trying to open files in procfs, mine uses sysfs directly. You may need to update pciutils. 2. CONFIG_PCI should be enabled at least.

Comment: @AndyShevchenko, /sys is empty as well. I even enabled "/proc/config.gz" in the menuconfig, and it doesn't show up either.

Comment: And you mounted procfs, sysfs, etc ?

Comment: Is the kernel mainline (untouched)? If it comes from a Freescale BSP, I suggest (if you did not) using the default config (make xxxxx_defconfig usually) and starting from that point configuring the needed options.